# sudo msfconsole [*] Bundler failed to load and returned this error: help me

Tags: gemfile

┌─[alzaeem@Parrot]─[~/tools]
└──╼ $sudo msfconsole
[*] Bundler failed to load and returned this error:

'You have already activated bundler 2.1.4, but your Gemfile requires bundler 2.2.3. Since bundler is a default gem, you can either remove your dependency on it or try updating to a newer version of bundler that supports bundler as a default gem.'

[*] You may need to uninstall or upgrade bundler

Answer (score 1):

you have to update your bundler version, in this case:

```
gem install bundler -v 2.2.3
```

for other gems

```
gem install 'gem name' -v 'version'
```

Comment: You should do this also
`sudo gem uninstall 'gem name' -v 'version_to_remove'`.
In this case 
`gem uninstall bundler -v 2.1.4`